# SOLR gives suggestions but no results

Tags: catalogsearch, enterprise-1.14, solr

I have a new version of SOLR 3.6 with Magento 1.14. I am getting search suggestions with the correct number but I do not get results. I have tried cache clearing, re-indexing etc.

One side note: I do have a version of SOLR running as port 8983 for Magento version 1.12 (And it works)

I am running this version of SOLR under port 8984

I used the tutorial on Magento to setup the server.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_magento-solr.html

**EDIT:** I did get both sites to work by putting the SOLR dev server on a separate box. I would like to run everything on the same box.

[image]

Comment: IIRC dropdown suggestions are not powered by Solr. They're always from mysql fulltext.

Comment: @philwinkle does that mean the totals from the search results are also Full Text and not SOLR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started another version of SOLR on a different IP and it is working. I am sure there is a good way to run SOLR on the same IP but a different port. (I just couldn't get that to work.)